# Storm 1.2.2 and Kafka Version 2.x

Tags: apache-storm

I'm testing a case using Storm 1.2.2 and Kafka 2.x as my Spout. So i created a LocalCluster just for test purposes.

```
  TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("kafka_spout", new KafkaSpout<>(KafkaSpoutConfig.builder("MYKAFKAIP:9092", "storm-test-dpi").build()), 1);
        builder.setBolt("bolt", new LoggerBolt()).shuffleGrouping("kafka_spout");

        LocalCluster localCluster = new LocalCluster();
        localCluster.submitTopology("kafkaBoltTest", new Config(), builder.createTopology());
        Utils.sleep(10000);
```

After initialize this app i got the following:

```
9293 [Thread-20-kafka_spout-executor[3 3]] INFO  o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 0.10.1.0
9293 [Thread-20-kafka_spout-executor[3 3]] INFO  o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : 3402a74efb23d1d4
```

And after a lot of error:

```
9664 [Thread-20-kafka_spout-executor[3 3]] INFO  o.a.s.k.s.KafkaSpout - Initialization complete
9703 [Thread-20-kafka_spout-executor[3 3]] WARN  o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher - Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition storm-test-dpi-0
9714 [Thread-20-kafka_spout-executor[3 3]] WARN  o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher - Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition storm-test-dpi-0
9742 [Thread-20-kafka_spout-executor[3 3]] WARN  o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher - Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition storm-test-dpi-0
9756 [Thread-20-kafka_spout-executor[3 3]] WARN  o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher - Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition storm-test-dpi-0
9767 [Thread-20-kafka_spout-executor[3 3]] WARN  o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher - Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition storm-test-dpi-0
9781 [Thread-20-kafka_spout-executor[3 3]] WARN  o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher - Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition storm-test-dpi-0
9806 [Thread-20-kafka_spout-executor[3 3]] WARN  o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher - Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition storm-test-dpi-0
```

I think this problem is because of Kafka Version, as you can see the log is showing version "0.10.1.0" but my Kafka version is "2.x".

This is my pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.storm}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
            <version>${version.storm}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Where `${version.storm}` is 1.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to also declare the version of `kafka-clients` you are using. The `storm-kafka-client` POM sets the `kafka-clients` scope to `provided`. This means `kafka-clients` won't be included when you build. We do this so you can easily upgrade.

The reason it's even running for you is because you are using LocalCluster in some test code, where `provided` dependencies are present.

Add this to your POM, and it should work:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>your-kafka-version-here</version>
        </dependency>
```